# What is the expiry date time of the access token?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

When we implement the Client Credentials grant - [Protecting an API using Client Credentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) how long is the access token usable for (e.g. whats is the expiry date) before the client needs to generate a new access token?

Comment: i think the default expiry time is 3600 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a client you can define the lifetime of an access token

```
   var myClient =  new Client
    {
    ClientId = "testClient",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets =
        {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
        AccessTokenLifetime=3600
};
```

If you do not supply AccessTokenLifetime then it will default to 3600 which is an hour.   This means it will expire one hour after it is created

Answer (score 0):

FYI,
The expiry of a JWT will be represented as Unix epoch.

For instance

```
{
  "exp":1517988642,
   ...
}
```

which can be checked in a tool such as https://www.epochconverter.com/